# How to remove space from para in php

Tags: php

```
$string="This is testing para";
$string_withoue_whitespace=trim($string," ");
```

My expcted output is `Thisismypara` but <strike>whites</strike>paces are not removed.

**How can i remove <strike>white</strike> spaces within a paragraph in php**

Comment: sorry for my bad enghish. Thanks to correct my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string =  "This is testing para";
$new_string = preg_replace('/( *)/','',$string);
echo $new_string;
```

or

```
$string =  "This is testing para";
$new_string = str_replace(' ','',$string);
echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string_without_whitespaces = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

Use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) instead.

Also, if you are not sure there is only spaces, but some other non-printable chars, that look like a space - you can also use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
$string_without_whitespaces = preg_replace('~\s~', '', $string);
```

Comment: are you shure it's going to work ? Description
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )

Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

Comment: @poelinca: thanks ;-) The one thing I love php for - is the **obvious** parameters order ;-)

Comment: :) parameter type shold count too ( have a look at the description ) you're sending 3 string parameters and substr expects 1 string , 1 start ( integer ) and optional a third length ( integer ) , plus substr is used for a totaly different operation , it returns a part of the string , please edit

Comment: @poelinca: i've missed `str_replace` with `substr` :-S It is a middle of the working day past here, so I'm a little tired and unfocused :-)

Comment: np , everithing is good now , that's why i like stackoverflow becouse you can revise you're answer if you do mistakes